# Change screenshot default name

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, screenshot, preview.app

How can I change the default screenshot name, to whatever I have written on Preview search tool at the time of the screenshot. As a function on terminal or as a script. Using OS X Mavericks. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots can be saved to the clipboard instead of a file by holding down the  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  key in addition to the  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  and  <kbd>Command</kbd>  keys, according to [this Apple Support article.](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14212?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Then in `Preview.app`,  <kbd>Command</kbd>  - N will create a new document from the contents of the clipboard without having to specify a filename until you're ready to save it.